# Enabling pins of Arduino Due with direct port manipulation

Tags: arduino-due, port-mapping

I want to enable pin 13 on my SAM3X8E using direct port manipulation. On this chip the pin is bit 27 in port B, so I used `PIOB->PIO_PER = 1<<27;` to enable this pin, but it doesn't work. This pin keeps at 3.08V, the default value of non-initialized pins.

Here's my complete code:

```
#include <asf.h>

int main (void) {
  // Insert system clock initialization code here (sysclk_init()).
  board_init();
  sysclk_init();
  delay_init(sysclk_get_cpu_hz());
  PIOB->PIO_PER = 1<<27;
  PIOB->PIO_OER = 1<<27;
  while(1) {
    REG_PIOB_ODSR = 1<<27;
    delay_ms(1000);
    REG_PIOB_ODSR = 0<<27;
    delay_ms(1000);     
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following test:  Use `REG_PIOB_SODR = 1<<27;` to set the bit, and  `REG_PIOB_CODR = 1<<27;` to clear it.  If that works ok, see about enabling synchronous data output via the port's PIO_OWSR register.  (If it doesn't work ok, perhaps review section 31.6, “I/O Lines Programming Example”, on page 629 of Atmel document 11057, the Cortex datasheet.)

Section 31.5.5, “Synchronous Data Output”, on page 623 says in part:

> After reset, the synchronous data output is disabled on all the I/O lines as PIO_OWSR resets at 0x0.

I imagine that writes to REG_PIOB_SODR and  REG_PIOB_CODR should have effect after you enabled output by setting bits in PIOB->PIO_PER and PIOB->PIO_OER, which you did.  However, with the bit in PIO_OWSR being clear, synchronous data output isn't available, so writes to REG_PIOB_ODSR have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #define Led_ON  REG_PIOB_ODSR |= 0x8000000
    #define Led_OFF REG_PIOB_ODSR &= ~0x8000000
    //for Arduino Due
    PIOB->PIO_PER |= 0x8000000;//led
    PIOB->PIO_OER |= 0x8000000;//led
```

And then call Led_ON and Led_OFF